# Using OAuth with Web API overkill if not using external identity provider?

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I've been looking at OAuth as an authentication mechanism using some RESTful web services created using Web API. It appears to be using OAuth 2.0.

I understand that one of OAuths primarily goals was to allow for authentication against another identity provider (Facebook, Google, etc.) without having to share passwords between systems. However, is it overkill to use OAuth if you are only using the built in token provider?

That is, the system that I need to create the web services for stores its own identities as opposed to going outside the system. I've been looking at HMAC too, but OAuth (through a Web API project) is far simpler to implement.

If not OAuth in this scenario,then is HMAC the preferred method?